# Twig month format in pt_BR is adding the dot

Tags: twig

{{date|date('Y-M-d')}}

When doing this, the month is being returned like 'jan.' 'fev', and not 'jan', 'fev'. Has anyone seem something like that?

Answer (score 1):

This seems very strange. I can't reproduce the error. Check out this Twig fiddle to see the result of executing the code that you posted: http://twigfiddle.com/zadbqa  I can't see the dot in the month names.

Where does the `date` variable come from in your template?